# how to delete xcode derived data WITHOUT xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

I want to update my xcode from xcode 9.2 to 9.3. but in the App store when I press update button, it shows the alert like the picture above. it is only xcode, when I update the itunes, it can update smoothly.

even though in fact I have a lot of space 
[image]

and then I DELETE my Xcode from my application. and I try to download the xip file from apple, but it I can't expand my xip file to dmg

[image]

I got confused. and then I download an app called cleanMyMac3. and i find that my Xcode Derived data and ios device support takes a lot of memory.

I expect thats why I can't update the xcode. so how can I delet those folder manually, since I can't find it in the finder? I charge a lot of money if I have to clean using cleanMyMac3

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just open Finder and and press command+shift+g a dialog box will appear and paste `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` in the text box and press go.

It will navigate you to the `Derived Data` folder.

You can pin it at left side of the Finder to use it in future.

To pin it in Finder just drag and drop derived data folder under favourite option.:)

[image]